# Is there any option for dynamical extension of class in PHP?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, dynamic

What I meant is to change the base class for a derived class dynamically. For example there are two classes `B1` and `B2`. When I run a php script with parameter `class=b1`, a class (say `class D`) defined in that script should extend `class B1` else if parameter is `class=b2` it should extend `B2`.

Expect something like this

```
class B1{
    // some codes 
}

class B2{
    // some codes 
}

switch($_GET['class']){
   case 'b1': $baseclass = "B1"; break;
   case 'b2': $baseclass = "B2"; break;
}


class D extends $baseclass{
    // some codes 
}
```

Is there any option in PHP like that? Please suggest me if any option is available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a BAD design approach.

Comment: @hek2mgl : I have found a solution for my problem. Please verify if it is a good approach or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not suggest to dynamically extends classes. Although it is possible it is a really bad design that will have many unwanted side effects. To tell at least one: How will you generate an API documentation for that class(es)? (Knowing this is the smallest problem)

With the additional info from the comments: you want to build something like a ORM that can work with different databases, I was thinking first about PDO. It allows to access a large set of databases using the same interface.

If you for whatever reason need a non PDO solution you could make a design like this:

```
<?php

class DatabaseStorage {

    /**
     * @var DB_Mysql|DB_SQLite|DB_Postgres ...
     */
    protected $database;


    /**
     * @param DB_Mysql|DB_SQLite|DB_Postgres ... The inner database to be used
     */
    public function __construct($database) {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    /**
     *  Connect to the database
     */
    public function connect($host, $user, $password) {
        $this->database->connect($host, $user, $password);
    }


    /**
     * Query the database
     */
    public function query($query) {
        return $this->database->query($query);
    }

    // other methods may follow
}
```

Then use the class like this:

```
$databaseType =$_GET['databaseType'];

// you should check the value before using it!!
/*if(!is_valid_database_type($databaseType)) {
    die('BAD input');
}*/

$databaseClass = 'Database' . $databaseType;
$database = new $databaseClass();

// use $database as argument to the storage constructor
$storage = new DatabaseStorage($database);
```

However this is just an example. You'll find other ways to prevent from dynamic code generation,

Comment: :) Good luck! As I mentioned, its just an example how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for my problem. Guys please verify whether this is a correct approach or not.

Now i store B1 and B2 in two seperate files but class name is same and require the file needed dynamically.

```
b1.php
class B{
    // some codes 
}

b2.php
class B{
    // some codes 
}
```

now extend D like this

```
$baseclass = $_GET['class'];

require_once($baseclass.'.php');

class D extends B{
    // some codes 
}
```

this one works for me. :)

Comment: @hek2mgl Is this a fine method?

Comment: I would say NO!! Don't do that!!! :) The idea itself , dynamic selection of the base class, is bad design. I would really like to give a suggestion for your application that will work without this but therefore I would need more information about your application. That might be 'too much' for stackoverflow

Comment: @hek2mgl Its just a part of application. just writing an ORM for my application. class D in the example will be a general class available for the users to use db. B1, B2 etc will be different base classes for different type of databases. Its selection really depends on a value stored in a config file (just said as a parameter for an example only). So if mysql selected the base class D will be derived from base class specifying the access to mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

It is never possible in php language.